# Change tracking in XML with condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML with change tracking.

Objective:  If XML file consists of an element `CT="ACCEPT"` then accept/print all tags with `<atict:add>` and ignore `<atict:del>`. -if XML file consits of an element `CT="REJECT"` then accept/print all tags with `<atict:del>` and ignore `<atict:accept>` .

But, in case the XML does not contain any CT element then it should insert `ADD` and `DEL` elements accordingly(wherever `<atict:add>` and `<atict:del>` are present.

I am able to achieve the first part of the question but not the second part.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DM xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict" CT="ACCEPT">
<PARA>abcd <atict:del>efghi</atict:del><atict:add>1456790
</atict:add></PARA>
</DM>
```

XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="atict:del[ancestor::DM/@CT='ACCEPT']"/>
<xsl:template match="atict:add[ancestor::DM/@CT='REJECT']"/>
<xsl:template match="atict:add">
<xsl:element name="ADD">
<xsl:value-of select='.'/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="atict:del">
<xsl:element name="DEL">
<xsl:value-of select='.'/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is i am getting `ADD/DEL` element when CT element is present. I don't require `ADD` ,`DEL` element when `CT=ACCEPT` or `CT=REJECT` element is present in the result XML.

Could you please help me to put a condition if possible.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="atict:del[ancestor::DM/@CT='ACCEPT']"/>

  <xsl:template match="atict:add[ancestor::DM/@CT='REJECT']"/>

  <xsl:template match="atict:add[ancestor::DM/@CT='ACCEPT']">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="atict:del[ancestor::DM/@CT='REJECT']">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="atict:add[not(ancestor::DM/@CT)]">
    <xsl:element name="ADD">
      <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="atict:del[not(ancestor::DM/@CT)]">
    <xsl:element name="DEL">
      <xsl:value-of select='.'/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should do the job properly.

Basically you need to handle the `atict:del` or  `atict:add` tag separately when then are required to be removed or kept, and also changed to `<ADD>` or `<DEL>` elements.

See it working live here: http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEv2

Answer (score 0):

After searching in the web,I believe this may also be the XSLT:

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="atict:add[not(ancestor::DM/@CT='ACCEPT')]"  >
<xsl:element name="ADD">
<xsl:value-of select='.'/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="atict:del[not(ancestor::DM/@CT='REJECT')]">
<xsl:element name="DEL">
<xsl:value-of select='.'/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="atict:del[ancestor::DM/@CT='ACCEPT']"/>
<xsl:template match="atict:add[ancestor::DM/@CT='REJECT']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```